# Undefined control sequence: mathcall

Tags: errors

I wonder why `\mathcal{f}` is not working but `\mathcall{f}` does (the print looks fine), even with the `undefinedcontrolsequence` error. This happens inside the equation mode and inside the text.`

```
\begin{equation}
 U_{TT} = A e^{-bR} - \sum_{n=3}^5 \mathcall{f}_{2n} (bR) \frac{C_{2n}}{R^{2n}}
\end{equation}
```

..in which `$\mathcall{f}_{2n}(R)$` are the damping functions from eq. (98).

Comment: Notice the difference in argument delimiter: parens `()` are not the standard LaTeX delimiter (the case that doesn't work), but braces `{}` are (the example that works).

Comment: The command is `\mathcal` with a single ell. On the other hand, `\mathcal{f}` is wrong to begin with, because `\mathcal` only applies to uppercase letters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a typo

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting. (1) `\mathcall` is undefined
(2) `\mathcal` (this is the correct name) only makes sense with uppercase letters, such as `\mathcal{F}`
(3) `\mathcal(f)` tries to apply `\mathcal` to `(` and the result will be unpredictable
(4) `\mathcal{f}` will only print random rubbish (maybe an `f`)

Comment: Sorry, yes, in both cases I write {}. The issue is that for the correct command: "\mathcal{f}", the pring goes as: "{", and the undefined control sequence error doesn't appear. Strangely, with "\mathcall{f}", the print is fine.. and the error shows, lots of them by now with the same typing.

Comment: With `\mathcall{f}` an error is raised and the undefined command is ignored, so you just get the output of `{f}`, the same as `f`. With `\mathcal{f}` you get arbitrary rubbish.

Comment: @egreg: In `stix` or `dutchcal` there is a `\mathcal{f}` for lower case `f`, but it's `\mathscr{f}` in the other: can never remember which is which.

Comment: I solve it with $\textit{f}_{2n}(R)$, it works also into the equation mode, and no u.c.s. error arise. Thanks.